# Incongruent roots modulo 13 of $x^3$ + 12

Tags: number-theory

Find the incongruent roots modulo 13 of $x^3$ + 12. By trial and error, I know x=1,3, and 9. But how can I provide a solution where I apply various theorems? I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Solving cubics isn't a triviality.  Having found one root, $1$ let's say, you could use it to factor the cubic into $(x-1)$ times a quadratic.  Then you could use the quadratic formula, but you'd still have to extract a square root. Or you could use Cardano's formula, but again you'd still need to extract some roots. Hard to imagine that this would be any more efficient than just trying the $13$ values.

Comment: True. It's efficient for me to try 0 to 12 too. However, my professor sometimes require a solution where you apply what she previously taught.

Comment: So, use the factoring idea I mentioned. I believe you get $x^3+12\equiv (x-1)(x^2+x+1)\pmod {13}$  (check that).  So now you have an ordinary quadratic.  As I say, you then have to extract a square root.

Comment: @lulu: You are obviously a competent person in maths and that is why I ask you, please, explain to me the error in the following:  in $\Bbb F_{13}$ if $x\ne0$ we have $x^{12}=1$ then $x^3=\sqrt[4]{x^{12}}=\sqrt[4]1$. But the fourth roots of $1$ are $1,5,8$ and $12$ while the cubic root of $1$ are $1,3$ and $9$. Thanks you. Best regards.

Comment: Not sure what point you are making.  Yes, for any non-zero residue you have $n^3$ is a fourth root of $1$.  What do you want to do with that?  It's true, in this particular case, your equation is the same as $n^3\equiv 1\pmod {13}$.  But you still need to solve that somehow.  For such a small modulus, this is easy...not so easy if the modulus is gigantic.

Comment: @lulu: you say  **Yes, for any non-zero residue you have  $n^3$
 is a fourth root of $1$**. But the four fourth roots of $1$ are $1,5,8$ and $12$ while the three cubic roots of $1$ are $1,3$ and $9$.

Comment: @Piquito  Yes...so what?  I am not seeing the point here.  The given congruence, $n^3\equiv -12\pmod {13}$ is equivalent to $n^3\equiv 1 \pmod {13}$ so the problem asks you for the cube roots of $1$.  Again, that's literally equivalent to the original problem.  If you had a primitive root $\pmod {13}$ it would be easy, but lots of things are easy if you are given a primitive root.

Comment: To @BenjaminJoshuaCalanza Hint: $x^3+12 \equiv x^3 -1 \equiv (x-1)(x^2+x+1) \equiv (x-1)(x^2-12x+27) \pmod{13}$.

Comment: To @Piquito : You know $x^3 \equiv 1^{1/4} \pmod{13}$. Since you mention the fourth roots of $1$, we can manually find $x$ in such cases: $x^3 \equiv 1,5,8,12$. Then you solve for $x$. I think your confusing the fact that $x^3$ is a cubic root of 1. It is not.

Comment: @D S: That's right. I see clear now. Thanks you very much.